# how to restart a program in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am programming a simple game using tkinter and want an option at the end to be able to replay the game, but I am not sure how I would go about doing it. I would like to be able to go back to the beginning where i define init. Also is there a way I could do this and not have to quit it so I could save scores as the player keeps playing.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        player_dice = []
        for i in range(1,6):
            x = random.randint(1,6)
            player_dice.append(x)
            self.label = Label(master, text = x , fg = "red").grid(row =0, column =i+1)

        self.label = Label(master, text = "Dice:" , fg = "red").grid(row =0, column =1)

        self.hi_one = Button(master, text="one", command= lambda: say_one(player_dice)).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.hi_two = Button(master, text="two", command= lambda: say_two(player_dice)).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
```

Here is where I would like to add a button to loop back to init.

```
def num(var, die, dlist):
    new_window = Toplevel(root)
    if die == 1:
        if guess == total:
            result = Message(new_window, text = "You Win").grid(row = 1, column = 1) 
        else:
            result = Message(new_window, text = "You Lose").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
            restart = Button(new_window, text = "Play Again", command = ?????).grid(row=1, column = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way:

Just add a function `resetBoard` that resets your game.
Obviously there are various parts of the UI that don't need to be re-set, so those can go into `__init__`, the rest can go into `resetBoard()` and you can (possibly) call `resetBoard()` from within `__init__`.

Correct way:

Implement an MVC or MVP pattern: Separate your data and logic from your UI. Your view (UI) should reflect whatever is in your model, then reseting the game is just a question of reseting the model and firing the correct events so the view is updated (highly simplistic, but the very useful model-view-XXX patterns cannot be properly explained in just a few words.)

Comment: thanks very much. i am just a beginner so I think i will try the easiest way first. I put all I had in __init__ in a function defined resetboard(self) and then in __init__ called self.restboard() but got AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'reset_board'